# What is the success rate to comply Magento 2 split database concept?

Tags: database, magento2.3.3

Currently, we are trying to do the Magento split database concept to split its catalog, checkout, and order master databases.

Magento documentation only speak about the very high level

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_manual.html

We know that our custom modules and extensions play more roles here. Do we have any technical process to verify whether our existing code will support the split database concept? Also, what is the success rate on this if anybody tried before?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is not about how to split database calls (this is the easiest), the problem is to maintain all this.

usually we hit php limits and need to start php backend auto-scaling. database is not much of a problem.

if you really looking for database split, check [PorxySQL](https://www.proxysql.com/) or [mysqlrouter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/) , it will help you to split queries between multimaster mysql cluster. loop database calls to localhost, then push query where you need to.

```
          /-> node.checkout -> db.checkout \
user -> lb -> node.frontend -> db.forntend  |
          \-> node.admin -> db.admin       /
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried and failed with magento 1 on open source edition. The trouble with having master and slave db is that replication has overhead and thus delay.

You end up with a ton of errors as read and write users are essentially in different places.

I'm not sure this is the right solution any more. I note how cloud commerce doesnt support this.

Why are you trying to do it? Is it to increase capacity for concurrent users. Plenty of options available.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303972/70343